# Check if two binary trees are equal

Tags: python, python-2.x, tree

I've recently solved the [LeetCode's "Same Tree" problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/#/description):

> Given two binary trees, write a function to check if they are equal or
>   not.
>
> Two binary trees are considered equal if they are structurally
>   identical and the nodes have the same value.

The problem itself and the idea is simple: traverse the tree in a way that preserves the structure - returning `None` for non-existing left or right sub-tree.

Here is the complete working code:

```
from itertools import izip


def traverse(node):
    if not node:
        yield None
    else:
        yield node.val
        if node.left:
            for val in traverse(node.left):
                yield val
        else:
            yield None
        if node.right:
            for val in traverse(node.right):
                yield val
        else:
            yield None


class Solution(object):
    def isSameTree(self, p, q):
        """
        :type p: TreeNode
        :type q: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        try:
            for node_p, node_q in izip(traverse(p), traverse(q)):
                if node_p != node_q:
                    return False
        except StopIteration:
            return True

        return True
```

It was accepted by the Online Judge, but the code looks a bit lengthy. Is there a way to further simplify or improve the solution? Also, is it the most optimal way to solve the problem?

Note that I cannot use `yield from` since the OJ is Python 2.7 only.

---

FYI, here is what LeetCode uses as a Tree/Node:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a check `if not node`, can't you just ignore checking `if node.left` and `if node.right`? How about:

```
def traverse(node):
    if not node:
        yield None
    else:
        yield node.val
        for val in traverse(node.left):
            yield val
        for val in traverse(node.right):
            yield val
```

Also in line `for node_p, node_q in izip(traverse(p), traverse(q))` you have misleading variable names, since `node_p` and `node_q` aren't actually nodes, but their values.

Was class `Solution` a requirement? Because it isn't easy to use:

```
s = Solution()
result = s.isSameTree(root1, root2)
```

It'd be easier to use a function instead:

```
result = isSameTree(root1, root2)
```

Or maybe

```
result = root1.isSameAs(root2)
```

And if you want to keep the class then `Solution` isn't a great name either because you can apply different arguments to it. `Checker` or `Comparator` would indicate performed functionality more clearly.

Comment: Great point about simplifying the traversal! The Solution was a leetcode constraint, yeah. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

## Exit the check early

Basically, you have a recursive traversal operation that traverses the two input trees sort of in parallel. The advantage of that approach is that you may exit algorithm *as soon as* you get to a pair of corresponding nodes with different values:

```
def bst_trees_are_identical_impl(p, q):
    if not p and not q:
        return True
    if p and q:
        if p.val != q.val:
            return False
        if not bst_trees_are_identical_impl(p.left, q.left):
            return False
        if not bst_trees_are_identical_impl(p.right, q.right):
            return False
        return True
    return False


def bst_trees_are_identical(p, q):
    return bst_trees_are_identical_impl(p, q)


class Solution(object):
    def isSameTree(self, p, q):
        """
        :type p: TreeNode
        :type q: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return bst_trees_are_identical(p, q)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I believe that the OP's code already short-circuits and returns as soon as a single pair of nodes are unequal; ironically, your code solves the _actual_ problem in OP's code, which is that it only checks for equivalent traversals (your code checks for true equivalency) :p

Comment: @gntskn There are many words that I don't understand. :p

Answer (score 6):

> Also, is it the most optimal way to solve the problem?

I don;t think so.  You are recursively using generators, so if your tree has n nodes, you'll have created and used n generators.

Plus if 2 trees have the same pre-order traversal but a different structure this would be incorrect.

```
1
 \
  2
 /
3
```

vs

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
```

Comment: It would seem that in this case we have a relaxation: the input trees are not expected to be valid binary search trees. All we do, is make sure that both the trees are of the same topology and content.

Answer (score 3):

## Criticism of Code as Given

As [Josh mentioned in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/159160/67347), your code as given fails for several cases where two trees have the same preorder traversal but different structure. However, for completeness's sake:

**Use Python 3 if at all possible**

Python 3 removes a lot of various headaches and annoyances with the language, and in the case of your code, two particular features add a lot of simplicity: `yield from` and lazy sequence functions (`zip`, in this case).

In Python 3, your `traverse` function is as simple as:

```
def traverse(tree):
    if tree is None:
        yield None
    else:
        yield tree.val
        yield from traverse(tree.left)
        yield from traverse(tree.right)
```

And your import of `izip` is unnecessary.

**Follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)**

One of the nicest things about the Python community is the official style guide; following it guarantees consistency with existing code, and makes it easy for others to read and use your code without any unnecessary surprises. Tools such as flake8 and pycodestyle exist to help you check for conformance.

**Use clearer naming conventions**

`traverse` is slightly misleading – it may imply that your function traverses *anything*, when in fact it only traverses *trees*. Name it as such (e.g., `traverse_tree`); better yet, since it's a specific type of traversal (namely, preorder), name it that (`traverse_tree_preorder`, perhaps).

'isSameTree' is also somewhat misleading: you are not checking if these are the *same* tree (which is identity), but if they are *equivalent* trees. The name `trees_are_equal` might be more fitting.

**Try/Catch Block in `isSameTree` is unnecessary**

A `for` loop terminates when `StopIteration` is thrown; you don't need to check for it manually.

**Avoid using classes unless you need to track state**

The purpose of a class is to combine *state* with *behavior*; your equality function doesn't need any state, it only needs behavior. If possible, just drop the `Solution` class altogether.

**Conversely, *do* use classes when you do need state!**

Given the context of your code, it might not be possible to directly alter the tree class, but since both of the functions you define only make sense for trees, it would make more sense to place them inside the class definition.

You get some other benefits out of this, too, such as the ability to override [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) for the Tree type so that you can use simple `tree1 == tree2` syntax.

**Code as given, with suggested modifications**

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def traverse_preorder(self):
        yield self.value
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left.traverse_preorder()
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right.traverse_preorder()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # Keep in mind, this doesn't actually check for tree equality!
        for (l, r) in zip(self.traverse_preorder(), other.traverse_preorder()):
            if l != r:
                return False
        return True
```

## Correct Way to Solve the Problem

The simplest way to describe tree equality is actually recursively: two trees are equal if their values are equal and their two pairs of subtrees are equal (this is equivalent to the definition LeetCode provides, but it makes the correct algorithm more obvious).

If we transcribe this definition directly into Python:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (other is not None and self.value == other.value and
                self.left == other.left and self.right == other.right)
```

Breaking this down: first, we check that the second tree is not `None`; then, we check that our values match; then we recursively call `__eq__` for both the left and right subtrees. Since `__eq__` has a sensible default definition for `None`, we don't need to do any other edge case checking for those.

**Is this solution optimal?**

Without doing benchmarking, this solution is likely to be perfectly satisfactory for most cases. However, one major shortcoming is that since it relies on recursion, it is possible to cause a stack overflow if you pass it a binary tree of too much height (specifically, ~1000 nodes tall for CPython). To avoid this, you'll need to manually simulate recursion using a stack; this gets a lot messier, but doesn't suffer from stack overflow:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __eq__(self, other):
        from collections import deque

        pairs = deque()
        pairs.append((self, other))

        while len(pairs) > 0:
            s, o = pairs.pop()
            if (s is None) != (o is None) or s.value != o.value:
                return False
            else:
                pairs.append((s.left, o.left))
                pairs.append((s.right, o.right))

        return True
```